# How to reorder category in bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made a bar chart:
[image]

The category label on the right side doesn't follow the numerical order. My code is as following:

```
ggplot(dat3, aes(variable, value, fill = AnnualCompensation, color = AnnualCompensation)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Number of Workers", labels = comma)
```

How can I reorder the category on the right side and make the bars in the chart follow the order `AnnualCompensation`?

And below is the dataset that I used:
[image]

Comment: You need to change the order of the factor levels of `AnnualCompensation`. For example, `dat3$AnnualCompensation <- factor(dat3$AnnualCompensation, levels = <your desired order>)`. Or set the levels directly `levels(dat3$AnnualCompensation) <- <your desired order>`. Or use `relevel`.

Comment: Might be worth doing a google search on the `fct_reorder()`  function in the `forcats` package, I've found that function to be be particularly useful for exactly this situation. Not always a fan of adding new package dependencies, but I have yet to find a base R way to accomplish the same end in as few keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

You must reorder your levels in R- Most likely your levels are following that order. use `levels()` to see which is assigned to level 1,2,...